# edit and comment on a word document in a discernible way for another person

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

There is a word document sent from a friend who asked me to correct grammar mistakes and vocabulary mistakes in it. I want the end result to be a word document with totally visible and easily discernible fixes, so that the other person can easily notice their mistakes without needing to open each and every comment. Are there any solutions other than choosing a different font color and styling, and other than commenting in word 2016 that could make it possible for me to do so?

Consider this mistake: "the bar graph gives information  the amount of rainfall in millimeter  all throughout the year"

I want to fix it like this: "the bar graph gives information **about**  the amount of rainfall in millimeter**s**  all throughout the year"

I know that using html tags I can do that here in stackoverflow, but are there any solutions for fixing a document sent from another user, and letting that user notice those fixes done by you in a very straight-forward and easily noticeable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: I need to use track changes in the Review tab in word 2016.

[image]